# How to setup RPC Node of solana?

Tags: rpc, solana

I want to setup a full node of solana  not a validator or voter node jsut to get the data of blockchain on local machine how could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a local RPC node, know that the specs required are very high, currently 12 cores, 256GB RAM, and 1TB of NVME SSD space.  More info at https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-reqs

If you want to run an RPC node, the only additional command line argument that you must provide is `--no-voting`, and you don't need the voting args, so for example, you'd run:

```
solana-keygen new -o identity.json
solana-validator \
  --rpc-port 8899 \
  --entrypoint entrypoint.devnet.solana.com:8001 \
  --limit-ledger-size \
  --log ~/solana-validator.log \
  --no-voting \
  --identity identity.json
```

Otherwise, you can follow all of the instructions at https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start

Comment: can you mention the steps to setup the rpc nodes.please

Comment: When I pasted your validator.sh it throws an error

log file: solana-validator-Dak5TgCYsUM4ZpDLesbsFT9unwZvbgnUKhUWVbZgvxys.log
/home/shahbaz/Solana/solana-release/bin/validator.sh: line 3: --vote-account: command not found
/home/shahbaz/Solana/solana-release/bin/validator.sh: line 4: --rpc-port: command not found
/home/shahbaz/Solana/solana-release/bin/validator.sh: line 5: --entrypoint: command not found

Comment: I updated the answer with one more needed flag. and the `\\` at the end of each line in the command is important, it tells the shell to continue the same command on a new line

Comment: 've pasted your validator.sh and run the command validator.sh It shows nothing and when I check on gossip my node is not listed